# What does "dead as a door nail" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does *dead as a door nail* mean?
Is it used in set phrases, or is it normally used in any context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Dead as a doornail* is one of the many idiomatic similes used for emphasis (to intensify the adjective). Thus, it simply means *dead*, *very dead*, *quite dead*, *certainly dead*, etc. It can be used figuratively or literally in any context.

Another simile that comes to mind is *poor as a church mouse*, which simply means *dirt poor*, *very poor*, *flat broke*, etc.

---

*I'm sure Cambridge and Longman still publish compendiums of English similes, proverbs and idioms. They're fun to peruse.*

Answer (score 15):

It would not be right to discuss this idiom without reference to this quote from the opening of Dickens's *A Christmas Carol*:

> Mind! I don't mean to say that I know, of my own knowledge, what there is particularly dead about a door-nail. I might have been inclined, myself, to regard a coffin-nail as the deadest piece of ironmongery in the trade. But the wisdom of our ancestors is in the simile; and my unhallowed hands shall not disturb it, or the Country's done for. You will therefore permit me to repeat, emphatically, that Marley was as dead as a door-nail.

Comment: Dickens was paid by the word, and so more than one of his books opens with this kind of waffle. Fortunately for his fans, he was also very, very good at it.

Answer (score 4):

From the *New Oxford American Dictionary*:

> **doornail** (noun):
>   a stud set in a door for strength or as an ornament.
>
> **(as) dead as a doornail**: quite dead.

Note that it is “doornail” with no space.

Comment: Also note that, in this context, "quite" means "completely", as opposed to "to some extent" :-)

Comment: @psmears: I wasn't aware that there were *degrees of deadness* :-)

Comment: @adj7388: Of course there are degrees of deadness, especially in ironmongery, [as Dickens well knew](http://www.pagebypagebooks.com/Charles_Dickens/A_Christmas_Carol/Stave_1_Marleys_Ghost_p1.html) - "dead as a doornail", "dead as a dodo", "dead as that squirrel" etc ;-)

Comment: @adj7388, "There's a big difference between mostly dead and all dead. Mostly dead is slightly alive. With all dead, well, with all dead there's usually only one thing you can do."

Comment: "What's that?" "Go through his clothes and look for loose change."

Comment: @psmears, Peter, Martha: OK, OK, you've convinced me. :)

Comment: @adj7388: You should have stood your ground! Of course there are *degrees of deadness* - ranging from life in [The (fairly) Dead Sea](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2011/09/110928-new-life-dead-sea-bacteria-underwater-craters-science/) to [Monty Python's (totally) Dead Parrot](http://www.mtholyoke.edu/~ebarnes/python/dead-parrot.htm)

Comment: Hear, hear! The (Dead Parrot sketch)[http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vuW6tQ0218] presents the definitive list for describing just how dead something (in this case, a parrot) can be.